# ¿Crear y recorrer un array en jquery con foreach?

Tags: jquery

Cómo se puede crear un array multidimensional que contenga llaves y luego recorrerlo con foreach.

Es porque tengo un array con datos en php y quiero devolverlo con ajax a jquery.

Tengo esto y no funciona. Y quiero hacerlo con foreach();

```js
var persona = [
  var persona1 = ["nombre"=>"Luis","Edad"=>"32"],
  var persona2 = ["nombre"=>"Alex","Edad"=>"27"]

]
for(var i=0;i<persona.length;i++){
 alert(persona[i]["nombre"]);
}
```

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos que has intentado?, quizás un ejemplo de lo que hayas hecho?

Comment: Define "no funciona". ¿Qué errores te da?

Comment: Es que ni siquiera tienes los conceptos básicos de la sintaxis de JavaScript, el típico "Aprende JavaScript en 1 hora"... Tengo la solución, si la reabren te la pongo como respuesta pero deberías al menos leer algo sobre JS antes de intentar implementar código automagicamente...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tu sintaxis es errónea, para declarar el arreglo `personas` tendrías que hacer así

```
var persona = [
  persona1 = {"nombre": "Luis","Edad": "32"},
  persona2 = {"nombre": "Marcos","Edad": "15"},
]
```

Y ahí tu `for` funcionaría perfecto, pero si aun así quieres hacerlo con un `foreach` te dejo un Snippet funcionando:

```js
var personas = [
  persona1 = {"nombre": "Luis","Edad": "32"},
  persona2 = {"nombre": "Marcos","Edad": "15"},
]


personas.forEach(function(persona, index) {
  console.log("Persona " + index + " | Nombre: " + persona.nombre + " Edad: " + persona.Edad)
});
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: si muchas gracias. Y ahora otra duda, sí quisiera eliminar el nombre de persona1  probé delete persona1["nombre"] y no me lo elimina;

Comment: Hola! Sería persona[0].nombre = ""; acordate que para acceder a los atributos se usa el punto. Te  recomiendo que si buscás múltiples soluciones o alternativas a ese nuevo problema formules otra pregunta nueva así otros usuarios participan y aportan. Saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada colega! Para eso estamos! Recuerda aceptar la respuesta si resolvió tu pregunta para dar por cerrado el tema. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

La sentencia `foreach` más sencilla en JS es:

```
for(var i in personas){
    console.log(personas[i].nombre);
}
```

Sin embargo, la manera correcta de construir objetos es con las llaves `{}`, ya que con `[]` indicas **un arreglo**. Para construir tus objetos hay dos maneras:

- Asignación directa:

  ```
  var personas = [
    persona1 = {"nombre":"Luis","Edad":"32"},
    persona2 = {"nombre":"Alex","Edad":"27"}
  ]
  ```

  o solo

  ```
  var personas = [
    {"nombre":"Luis", "Edad":"23"},
    {"nombre":"Alex", "Edad":"27"}
  ]
  ```
- Definición (de objeto):

  ```
  function Persona(nombre, edad){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
  }

  var personas = [new persona("Luis", 32), new persona("Alex", 27)];

  for(pers in personas){
    console.log(pers.nombre);
  }
  ```

Te dejo un pequeño [tutorial sobre POO en JavaScript](http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/programacion-orientada-a-objetos-oop-con-javascript-c232l/) para que aclares tus dudas.